# How to reassign a new valuable to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

So I'm creating a very simple function to assign a certain number of push-ups and sit-ups to do each day. The code is as follows:

```
import random

def exercise_rep_num():
    situps = random.randint(50,75)
    situps_feedback = 'You need to do %s situps today!' % situps
    print(situps_feedback) 

    pushups = random.randint(25,65)
    pushups_feedback = 'You need to do %s pushups today!' % pushups
    print(pushups_feedback)

    if situps >= 70:
        print("Making it easier...")
        pushups = random.randint(25,40)
        print(pushups_feedback)

    elif pushups >= 60:
        print("Making it easier...")
        situps = random.randint(30,60)
        print(situps_feedback)

    elif pushups >= 60 and situps >= 70:
        print("Making it easier... Hooray! No workout tofay :)")

exercise_rep_num()
```

I want the function to be able to change the "pushups_feedback" and "situps_feedback" values once the "if statements" commence. For example, I got a "situps" value of 71 so the pushups value was supposedly decreased. However, the function printed "pushups_feedback" as the same value from earlier. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're setting `pushups`, then printing `pushups_feedback`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign to `pushups_feedback`, it substitutes the variable into the template at that time. It doesn't remember the relationship with the variable, so reassigning the variable doesn't update the string.

You could write a function that displays the message, and call that function in both places.

```
def print_pushups(pushups):
    pushups_feedback = 'You need to do %s pushups today!' % pushups
    print(pushups_feedback)
def print_situps(situps):
    situps_feedback = 'You need to do %s situps today!' % situps
    print(situps_feedback)

def exercise_rep_num():
    situps = random.randint(50,75)
    situps_feedback = 'You need to do %s situps today!' % situps
    print(situps_feedback) 

    pushups = random.randint(25,65)
    pushups_feedback = 'You need to do %s pushups today!' % pushups
    print(pushups_feedback)

    if situps >= 70:
        print("Making it easier...")
        pushups = random.randint(25,40)
        print_pushups(pushups)

    elif pushups >= 60:
        print("Making it easier...")
        situps = random.randint(30,60)
        print_situps(situps)

    elif pushups >= 60 and situps >= 70:
        print("Making it easier... Hooray! No workout tofay :)")

exercise_rep_num()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reformat the string after you update the amount as the string doesn't "remember" what variable is substituted into it.

```
pushups = random.randint(25,40)
print('You need to do %s pushups today!' % pushups)
```

---

You could also define a method like so to make a "shortcut" for all workouts

```
def feedback(workout, amt):
    return 'You need to do %d %s today!' % ( amt, workout)
```

Then

```
print(feedback('pushups', random.randint(25,40)))
```